# JavaScript innerHTML is undefined

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Struggling with why .innerHTML shows undefined, yet .length shows 1.

```js
var content = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
console.log(content.innerHTML);
console.log(content.length);
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<ul>
  <li>This is an item</li>
  <li>This is another item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a list. So you want index 0 of the result, like this: `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 6):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

> The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.

Use `[0]` to get first item:

```
console.log(content[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an (array-like) object. You can to get the one element you need with `content[0]`:

```js
//returns a collection of elements
var content = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

// single out the element you need
var tag = content[0];
console.log(typeof(content));
console.log(content.length);

//get the element's inner HTML
console.log(tag.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<ul>
  <li>This is an item</li>
  <li>This is another item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to target this element specifically, give it an id attribute, and then use getElementById. This is more efficient, and will return just a single element.